# Why was Vicki Fowler briefly given an American accent?

Tags: character, eastenders

In *EastEnders*, Vicki Fowler recently re-emerged, having apparently been living in the US, with probably the most unconvincing American accent ever.

What was funny was, about two weeks into her return the accent completely went away and she returned to such banal Cockney phrases as "Gawd bless my son, it's all gone a bit pear-shaped innit?".

Have the BBC explained why they made the decision to give Vicki an American accent only to get rid of it so quickly?

Comment: ***Recently*** re-emerged? In 2003?

Comment: Maybe he's catching up on back episodes, @Valorum? I do that when I discover a new series I'm interested in watching. I can watch 7 episodes a week while they release one new one a week. (Yes, I know _EastEnders_ is daily soap, but the theory applies.)

Comment: @FreeMan - I thought I'd maybe fallen into a timewarp

Comment: Ok, I'll give. What is an "American" accent? My mother was from New Jersey, father from Massachusetts, I've been to Maryland, Pennsylvania, Virginia, N/S Carolina, Florida, Georgia, Alabama, Texas, Louisiana, California, and Arizona. I have heard such a huge range of accents across the US that I couldn't pin even one as an "American" accent. Which one is it?
If anything, I'd say trying to coach someone on an "American" accent is an exercise in futility because we don't have one. We have many.

Answer (score 10):

The goal was to signify to audiences that she'd been [living in the US](https://web.archive.org/web/20061109051723/http://www.bbc.co.uk/eastenders/backstage/cast/interviews/interview_content/interview_scarlett_johnson_p2.shtml), even down to giving her a professional voice coach to make her accent convincing.

Eventually the producers just seem to have tired of it, presumably because the [press and public reaction was very critical](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/world-news/im-so-glad-ive-left-eastenders-1604470?int_source=amp_continue_reading&int_medium=amp&int_campaign=continue_reading_button#amp-readmore-target)

> **That American accent! What happened there?! Whose idea was it to drop it?**
>
> *I don't know. The producers knew that I had to have an American accent when I came into the show because my character had been living in America but it's not the kind of accent that you'd want to have for a long time on a show like EastEnders. It's not something that's going to fit in for a long period of time.*
>
> *What would have been perfect would have been to have it gradually fade out, but as you film eight episodes at a time, this would be nigh on impossible.*
>
> *The decision was made that in the story Vicki was coming to terms with the fact that she wanted to live in London so therefore she was going to make a conscious effort to fit in with everyone around her and blend in with London life.*
>
> <sub><sup>[BBC Interview - Scarlett Woman in the Square](https://www.bbc.co.uk/threecounties/read_this/2004/01/scarlett_johnson.shtml)</sup></sub>